# Alternatives to 2 way SSL

Tags: authentication, ssl

I would like to know if there are any alternatives to 2 way SSL. Is 2 way SSL is the only option to make sure the client and server are trusted to communicate? I have a self signed certificate for my client, will i be able to reuse the self signed certificate for the 2 ways SSL or should i get a new certificate from CA?

Comment: So do you need both the client's and the server's identity verified from the CA? Retrieving from a trusted CA is the only way to verify identity if the client and server have never communicated before. If you are in control of  both the client and server however you could hard-code the encryption keys for each other. Is this a website or browser-based application you are working on?

Comment: I have a browser based application and 2 web services (uses self signed certs). 
Browser app runs in client machine
1 web service runs in client machine
1 web service hosted in a different server but intranet.
Both the webservice will use a remote log webservice which will be out of the network. I want only my clients to use the remote log webservice.
Please suggest, how we can acheive a trusted connection.

Comment: I agree with Samuel. HTTPS requires the the client to add the server CA to its trust store prior calling the server. Now from the server side, identification of the caller is made via certificate or login/password authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Some sort of CA is the only real way to do it for the server. The client can verify it's identity with some sort of username-password system if you don't want to use a CA for the client. But the server needs to be verified before the client would send it's password (or key) to the server and a trusted CA is the only way to verify the server's identity.